# xml parser for ARM platform

Tags: xml-parsing, arm

I am looking for good and fast xml parser for ARM platform (I am using Beaglebone) . I have spent sometime searching in google, and got following parser libraries.
1.[libxml2](http://git.gnome.org/libxml2)
2.[ezxml](http://ezxml.sourceforge.net/)
3.[minixml](http://www.minixml.org/)

Can you please suggest a good parser for ARM platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all portable parsers - the platform really doesn't add any extra considerations beyond the usual: memory usage, performance, and whether you need a fully featured parser and DOM or something lighter weight using SAX.

I wouldn't expect the results to be substantially different from those when these libraries are used on x86.

libxml2 is fully featured. You'll probably want this one if doing heavy XPATH, schema validation or XSLT.   It's almost certain to be included in any Linux distro.